# Communication between ASP.NET frontend and Windows Service backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, ipc

I'm currently evaluating the options for adding a web UI to a .NET 4.5 application that is installed and running as a Windows Service.

The basic idea is that the service application is running 24/7 and collects various data from network devices and persists them in a local data store (esentially, it monitors these devices)

The web UI interface is used for data presentation and analysis purposes and to send command & control messages to the backend (i.e. the service layer) which in turn fowards these commands to the network devices.

The big difference to a "classic" multi-tier web application is that the service part has to run even if no user has been interacting with it through the web UI (therefore the idea is to have it run as a Windows Service).

I currently do not know how to mix this web part (request/response pattern, short running) with the service part (polling on the network, long running, 24/7).

My ideas so far:

1. **Embed IIS Core (or any other web server) into the service application:** would probably work but the embedded web server would not know about any existing IIS configuration on the same machine which makes integration and configuration not straightforward (e.g. ports, authentication, SSL etc.)
2. **Deploy an ASP.NET application on IIS and a separate service application:** the ASP.NET application would then just act as a facade to the service and would need a proper and reliable way to communicate with the service application (two-way IPC?).

Currently it feels as if 2 is the best option.

If so, are there any IPC recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is going to be closed because it's opinion based. But, yes, option #2 is the most commonly employed. Starting with vNext you will be able to self-host ASP.NET MVC applications (via OWIN) in Windows Services) so the Web UI could sit right in the service itself.

Comment: @Aristos: He needs to poll some network devices (most likely repeatedly) which makes an IIS-only app (so web app) not very suitable.

Comment: @MarcelN. right, the service part is actually the core part of the overall software system and the web ui is one way of looking at the data

Comment: 2nd option is good one. you'll have separate and loosely coupled layers. If the communication between the website and windows service is not real-time, then don't go for IPC, it would add complexity. simply think of a database/table when the website writes commands and the windows service reads them and process. once a command is processed windows service can delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest (and probably the worst) way is to embed all your logic to IIS and disable shutdown of your app (this way IIS app will run like a windows service).

> I currently do not know how to mix this web part (request/response pattern, short running) with the service part (polling on the network, long running, 24/7).

You shouldn't. Regarding the second case I would suggest to decouple your service app and web ui app as much as possible. This way you minimize dependencies and IPC (therefore improve scalability and stability).

The windows service in this case may implement its minimal role: `collecting various data from network devices and persists them in a local data store` (the only feature that requires 24/7). IIS app may implement all UI-related features (data presentation and analysis roles) and user command. This way you don't need to delegate all presentation features to the windows service app. IPC is used just for `sending command & control messages to the backend (i.e. the service layer) which in turn fowards these commands to the network devices`.

I suggest using message queue model (ZeroMQ, MSMQ, RabbitMQ, etc) that is asynchronous IPC with its advantages. From the other hand it is possible to use the database itself for the IPC: e.g. push the messages to some table (or collection if using NoSQL) and read them by the win service app. This is an alternative to message queues but in most cases is worse than it.

Comment: Thanks. I think "mix" was the wrong term - I surely do not want to mix both parts but rather make them communicate with each other in a reliable way.